# SQL optional condition in WHERE clause in Report Builder

Tags: mysql, reportbuilder3.0

I am creating a report with Microsoft Report Builder 3.0. I want to add an additional condition in WHERE clause depends on a boolean parameter @param. In programming it would be easy by appending the SQL String like:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE tblA.columnA = 'data' ";
if(param)
{
    sql += "AND tblA.columnB IN (SELECT column FROM tbl)";
}
```

But how to do it in pure SQL query? I try to use CASE but seems like it doesn't work that way. This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM tblA 
WHERE tblA.columnA = 'data'
CASE @param WHEN 1 THEN AND tblA.columnB IN (SELECT column FROM tbl) END
```

Comment: use `.` instead of `+`

Comment: how `CASE` is not working can u post what you have tried?

Comment: instead of writting `@param` directly to sql why don't you make a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use logic involving the parameter:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblA
WHERE
    columnA = 'data' AND
    (!param OR columnB IN (SELECT column FROM tbl));
```

The `WHERE` clause would evaluate to true if `columnA` contains `data`, and either the parameter is set to false, or the parameter is set to true and the subquery succeeds.

Comment: OP said condition needs to be added only when `param` is true and i guess in your logic it will apply always because there is possibility of having data in `OR` query which will be true

Comment: @PrateikDarji If `param` be false, then the entire second half of the `WHERE` clause would always evaluate to true, i.e. it would behave as if there is no second half.  If `param` be true, then we must check the subquery.  AFAIK this is the logic in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`param` is setting in client side so you need to make query on client side, you can use CASE query to achieve this just like below

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tblA 
           WHERE tblA.columnA = 'data' 
           AND CASE " +param+ "
               WHEN 1 THEN tblA.columnB IN (SELECT column FROM tbl) 
              ELSE 1 
           END";
```

I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM [tblA] WHERE tblA.columnA = 'data' AND 
    (@param <> 1 OR columnB IN (SELECT column FROM tbl)).
```

In short the optional condition can be put in a **OR** condition with the flag that you want to verify against. Say you have parameters passed in the procedure called @name and @dept and you want to retrieve all the results with name mentioned or results with name mentioned in the specific department then you can write it as

```
SELECT * FROM [Employees] WHERE Name = @name AND (Department = @dept OR @dept = 0)
```